# "People are quick to jump on the hype train"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Hi I am looking for a way of describing people who get easily convinced by something that draws a lot of interest. For example there's a new fashion brand everyone is wearing and they adapt it instantly. I have heard "jump on the hype train" is this the best way of saying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Hype Train](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/hype-train) is a slang term used to describe the high level of anticipation surrounding an upcoming release of a popular media franchise or an announcement of a new project, especially for video games, movies and TV series. In the video gaming community, the term may be used in a positive light to express one’s excitement, or conversely, to convey disappointment at a product that fails to meet high expectations.

So it seems that *jump on the hype train* is informal and 
that is used in an anticipatory sense. In other words, people aren't using or wearing the the product yet since it hasn't be released (if you're using this expression), but they also share or join the anticipation surrounding a product.

It is a variation of this well-known idiom:

> [jump on the bandwagon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jump_on_the_bandwagon)
>
> 1. (idiomatic) To profit from a craze; to join a trend.

This is used with a trend that has been established. In other words, the product has already been released, people are using it and it has become popular.

*Example.*

> 1. When she saw that all her friends had iPhones, she jumped on the bandwagon and bought one too.

You can also say

> 2. She jumped on iPhone bandwagon and bought the iPhone 7.

So I think you might want to consider *jump on the bandwagon* instead.

Comment: Thanks, no problem. However, you are encouraged to [wait longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. You are likely to receive more answers that way. :)